# Is it possible to convert Scala method into python method

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, serialization, pyspark

I wonder if we can convert a method defined in the Scala into a method in Python at runtime. I am learning Apache Spark Scala API as part of my project and looking for a way to convert Scala method into Python language recognizable format. 
My goal is to send method from Scala program to external Python program and Python program should be able to use or execute it.

Scala code => Lambda

```
line => line.split(" ")
```

Is there a way to convert this into code which Python can understand.

Definitely above example is very basic and naive. But There can be any possible method (considering generic ones for which Python also has functional support) and is there any known way to achieve the same? Can we use serialization to achieve the same? but will Python understand Scala serialized object?

Comment: You could run your Scala script inside of a subprocess from Python.  Other than that there is no way to run Scala code from python.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Scala functions inside pyspark.

First, create Hive UDF in Scala containing your code. Pack it in jar file, add the jar to `--jars` during spark execution. Then after you register your UDF you will be able to use it. For more details please visit this great blogpost:  https://dzone.com/articles/working-with-udfs-in-apache-spark

Comment: Thank you. But I am not looking for the creation of jars. At runtime, I want to  transfer scala method from running scala program to another running python program. The method in scala can be any user-defined method (assuming can be implemented in python). Possible to do?

Comment: No. If you have two separate processes you should rather think about exposing the Scala function via some RPC (remote procedure call) like REST.